# How to create option menu in Fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am working on a code where I need to create a option menu, I have followed some tutorials about how to implement this menu on  fragment activities, but for some reason the code that I'm working with does not show the menu. Does anyone knows what could be?

**ProfileFragment**

```
public class ProfileFragment extends Fragment {

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_profile, container, false);

}

@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.profile_menu, menu);
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();
    switch (id) {
        case R.id.edit_profile:
            break;
        case R.id.change_password:
            break;
        case R.id.log_out:
            break;

    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
 }
}
```

**XML**

```
        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#10c0bd"
            android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
            app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark" />
```

Comment: Where do you call `setSupportActionBar()` with your `Toolbar`? The `onCreateOptionsMenu()` related APIs only work on the ActionBar. You'd use the `Toolbar` APIs directly if you're not using an ActionBar.

Answer (score 0):

Possible its because you trying to set `setHasOptionsMenu(true);` on `OnCreate` instead of `OnCreateView`.

Try to delete `setHasOptionsMenu(true);` from `OnCreate` and add it in `OnCreateView`

Comment: you put `setHasOptionsMenu(true);` after return? You need to put it before return.

Comment: I also did that but it still doesn't appear

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) { 
inflater.inflate(R.menu.profile_menu, menu);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setHasOptionsMenu(true);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**First of all Override Create Method in Fragment** and write **setHasOptionsMenu(true)**

```
  @Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
}
```

**Then after override OnPrepareOptionMenu method in Fragment** and Write code which i place inside it.
I hide my Search Menu only. Similarly You can hide all menu item or selective item as per your choice.

```
   @Override
public void onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuItem item=menu.findItem(R.id.menu_search);
    if(item!=null)
        item.setVisible(false);
}
```